# Replace IP address from URI with another IP address using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String uri = "rtps://12.10.10.124/abc/12.10.22.10";
```

I'm trying to replace any first occurrence of IP address in this uri with let's say "127.0.0.1" using an efficient regex.
Taking into account that numbers with dots may be introduced in the uri at the end. The regex has to replace only the first occurrence of any IP-address in the URI.

Output would be:

```
uri = "rtps://127.0.0.1/abc/12.10.22.10";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String ipRegex = "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}";
String uri2 = uri.replaceFirst(ipRegex, "127.0.0.1");
```

This of course matches any 4 groups of 1-3 digits separated by 3 dots (eg: 999.999.999.999 will match), if you want something that matches only legal IP addresses, you could go for:

```
String ipRegex = "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)";
```

But I personally think this is overkill.

Comment: I've updated my question. I want it to match any first occurance of IP address

Comment: As mentioned by Andreas Henning, it's highly unlikely that the first occurance will be an illegal IP address. I'll stick with the first snippet of code there. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

`s/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/127\.0\.0\.1/`

transforms the first occurence of an ip address in a string to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: so what? he asked for a regex, and that's exactly what I gave him.

Comment: Technically this will match something like `39829589.0.0.00000` too.

Comment: although, of course, it is unlikely that `39829589.0.0.00000` occurs in an uri string before the ip address.

Comment: And I'd agree with you on that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = uri.replaceFirst("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+", "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do it with the `URL` class.

```
URI u = new URI(uri);
u = new URI(u.getScheme(), "127.0.0.1", u.getPath(), u.getFragment());
uri = u.toString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this throws the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtps`

Comment: @NullUserException Oh sorry, didn't see the protocol, I changed the code to use `URI` instead of `URL`.